# Retrofit 2 Handle Socket time out exception with custom Response

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I want to create a custom response in Interceptor for Retrofit 2 for the various exception, like Socket timeout, 404 error etc..

Below is my code:

```
Interceptor responseCodeInterceptor = (Interceptor.Chain chain) -> {
        Request request = chain.request();
        okhttp3.Response response = null;
        try {
            response = chain.proceed(request);

            if (response != null) {
                switch (response.code()) {
                    case 401:
                           // todo   
                       break;
                    case 404: // todo
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("status", "Error");
                jsonObject.put("errors", "Socket time out exception");

                ResponseBody body = ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), jsonObject.toString());

                return new Response.Builder().body(body)
                        .message("Socket time out exception")
                        .request(request)
                        .build();
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                DebugLog.print(ex);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utils.hideProgressBar();
            DebugLog.print(e);
        }

        return response;
    };
```

Now, my concern is, when I use the above code for "Socket timeout exception", it gives me exception like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: protocol == null
```

So, can anyone help me how I can create custom response in interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

It means you didn't set any value to the `protocol` property of your `Response` object.

You can do that in this way:

```
return new Response.Builder()
    ...
    .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1) // Or any other value that's suitable for your use case
    .build();
```

You can check the [Protocol](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Protocol.html) javadoc to see other allowed values